# Failed to start Puma as service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, puma

When I lanch the command `/home/centos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/bundle exec puma -C /home/centos/app/config/puma.rb` in the app folder I get no error :

```
[145103] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[145103] * Puma version: 5.2.1 (ruby 3.0.0-p0) ("Fettisdagsbulle")
[145103] *  Min threads: 1
[145103] *  Max threads: 5
[145103] *  Environment: production
[145103] *   Master PID: 145103
[145103] *      Workers: 1
[145103] *     Restarts: (✔) hot (✔) phased
[145103] * Listening on unix:///home/centos/app/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
```

But when I try to start Puma as service `service puma start && service puma status` I get :

```
● puma.service - Puma HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/puma.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-02-15 17:37:24 UTC; 938ms ago
  Process: 145289 ExecStart=/home/centos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/bundle exec puma -C /home/centos/app/config/puma.rb (code=exited, st>
 Main PID: 145289 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Feb 15 17:37:24 centos-s systemd[1]: puma.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Feb 15 17:37:24 centos-s systemd[1]: puma.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I don't understand why ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, just a too much parenthesis in the `config/puma.rb`

Comment: Inside the file in some place? I'm having this very problem